# What is the name of the Boolean function $f(x_1,...,x_n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-x_k)$?

Tags: terminology, boolean-algebra

Here is the function:
$$n\in\mathbb{Z}^+, f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}, f(x_1,...,x_n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-x_k)$$
This function just came to my mind and I found out that it can be used to generate any Boolean functions. However, I can't find its name on the internet. Is this function not "efficient" or something? I really want to know its name and why it is not so popular.

Comment: It is the wedge product of $\neg x_{k}$ where $1\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: Maybe something like [logical NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR) for many arguments?